# Query builder proper sintax for 4 joins + 3 where clauses (Laravel5.7)

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, join, php-7, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to get this MySQL query to work in laravel 5.7 **query builder**.
It works fine in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT c.Symbol
, s.SectorName
, cprs.strenght
, s.parentid
, ssbpi.Risklevel 
, ssbpi.ColumnType
FROM Companies AS c
JOIN Sectors AS s ON s.SectorID = c.SectorID
JOIN Company_PriceRS AS cprs ON cprs.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
JOIN SubSectorsBPIsData AS ssbpi ON ssbpi.subcategoryid = s.parentid
WHERE cprs.PostDate = '2017-05-08'
AND WHERE CompanyPriceRS.strenght = 'strong'
AND WHERE SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType = $ColumnType
```

*ColumnType is a variable that comes from a dropdown and it's already being captured and working properly.*

I have tried the normal way according to documentation:

```
$Completequerytry1 = DB::table('Companies')
 ->join('Sectors', 'Sectors.SectorID', '=', 'Companies.SectorID')
 ->join('CompanyPriceRS', 'CompanyPriceRS.CompanyID', '=', 'Companies.CompanyID')  
 ->$join('SubSectorsBPIsData ', 'SubSectorsBPIsData.subcategoryid', '=', 'Sectors.parentid')

 ->where('CompanyPriceRS.strenght', '=', 'strong')    
 ->where('SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType', '=', $ColumnType) 
 ->where('CompanyPriceRS.Postdate', '=', '2017-05-08'); 
 ->select('Companies.Symbol', 'Sectors.SectorName', 'CompanyPriceRS.strenght', 'Sectors.parentid', 'SubSectorsBPIsData.subcategoryid','SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType')
  ->limit(10);
->select('Companies.Symbol', 'Sectors.SectorName', 'CompanyPriceRS.strenght', 'Sectors.parentid', 'SubSectorsBPIsData.subcategoryid','SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType')
 ->limit(10);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($Completequerytry1);
```

**Error:**
*Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)"*

2. Using functions With several nested joins:

```
$Completequerytry1 = DB::table('Companies')
->join('Sectors', function ($join) use ($ColumnType) {
 $join->on('Sectors.SectorID', '=', 'Companies.SectorID')   
->join('CompanyPriceRS', function ($join2) { 
  $join2->on('CompanyPriceRS.CompanyID', '=', 'Companies.CompanyID')  
  ->join('SubSectorsBPIsData', function ($join3)  { 
  $join3->on('SubSectorsBPIsData.subcategoryid', '=', 'Sectors.parentid')

 ->where(function ($query1)  {
   $query1->where('CompanyPriceRS.strenght', '=', 'strong')  //filter 1
          ->where('SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType', '=', $ColumnType) //filter2
           ->where('CompanyPriceRS.Postdate', '=', '2017-05-08'); // filter 3
        });
    });    
});
})
->select('Companies.Symbol', 'Sectors.SectorName', 'CompanyPriceRS.strenght', 'Sectors.parentid', 'SubSectorsBPIsData.subcategoryid','SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType')
 ->limit(10);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($Completequerytry1);
```

**Error:** 
*ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined variable: ColumnType*

3: Then tried functions with nested WHERE

```
$Completequerytry1 = DB::table('Companies')
 ->join('Sectors', 'Sectors.SectorID', '=', 'Companies.SectorID')
 ->join('CompanyPriceRS', 'CompanyPriceRS.CompanyID', '=', 'Companies.CompanyID')  
 ->$join('SubSectorsBPIsData ', 'SubSectorsBPIsData.subcategoryid', '=', 'Sectors.parentid') //ERROR IS GIVEN ON THIS LINE

 ->where(function ($query1)  {
 $query1->where('CompanyPriceRS.strenght', '=', 'strong')    
         ->where('SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType', '=', $ColumnType) 
         ->where('CompanyPriceRS.Postdate', '=', '2017-05-08'); 
   });

->select('Companies.Symbol', 'Sectors.SectorName', 'CompanyPriceRS.strenght', 'Sectors.parentid', 'SubSectorsBPIsData.subcategoryid','SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType')
 ->limit(10);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($Completequerytry1);
```

**Error:** 
*Undefined variable: join*

Still don't know what i'm missing.
Should i create functions for the JOINs and the WHEREs ?
Running out of ideas. Thanks in advance for your insights :)

Comment: You have syntax errors in PHP. So check and fix your code.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Your problem is a syntax error. You should first have shown as much as possible that the constituent subexpressions were OK. Make it clear that your question is about *that error* & ask re your overall goal later in a new post. Ask one question per post.

Comment: When you can't find syntax errors, chop your code down until it is valid then add back the last thing to get invalid. You have many syntax errors here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the query was being sent to a variable directly from the controller, not to the view. 
I was doing this only for testing but it was using too much memory with `print_r();` function making impossible to get a result. Even when using `dd();` i wasn't getting what i wanted (I think it's because some sintax errors i had). 
So i passed the final variable to the view and it works fine since laravel could handle the data differently. 
Also i used `->limit(10);` to split the results and avoid memory overload.
Here is the final code working:

```
$Completequerytry1 = DB::table('Companies')
->join('Sectors', 'Sectors.SectorID', '=', 'Companies.SectorID')
->join('Company_PriceRS', 'Company_PriceRS.CompanyID', '=', 'Companies.CompanyID')
->join('SubSectorsBPIsData', 'SubSectorsBPIsData.subcategoryid', '=', 'Sectors.parentid')
->select('Sectors.SectorName', 'Companies.Symbol', 'Company_PriceRS.strenght', 'Sectors.parentid', 'SubSectorsBPIsData.Risklevel','SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType')

->where('Company_PriceRS.strenght', '=', 'strong')    
->where('SubSectorsBPIsData.ColumnType', '=','X') 
->where('Company_PriceRS.Postdate', '=', '2017-05-08') 
->limit(10)
->get();
return view('besttrades2', array('Completequerytry1' => $Completequerytry1)); //sending my query variable to the view
```

Then in the view only used:

```
<?= $Completequerytry1; ?>
```

or show it in whatever way you want. 
Sometimes it's better to have another project only for testing separately.